# Androidx Activity API belongs to which dependency?

Tags: android, androidx, build-dependencies

[This](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity) documentation shows how to add dependencies for Androidx Activity API. There it mentions `androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$activity_version` to be declared. In my project, only Androidx dependencies that I have declared are `appcompat`, `core`, `lifecycle`, `constraintlayout` and `recyclerview`. But still in my project I am able to use `androidx.activity.result.contracts.ActivityResultContracts`. How is this possible?

**EDIT:** I commented out all 3rd party dependencies and now, my entire dependencies section is as follows:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(fileTree(mapOf("include" to listOf("*.jar"), "dir" to "libs")))

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:runner:1.4.0")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0")

    // Materials design
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0")

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0")

    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0")

    val lifecycleVersion = "2.4.0-alpha03"
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycleVersion")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycleVersion")
}
```

Still I am able to import ***any*** `androidx.*` library in my project.

Comment: androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$activity_version, this library just provides extra extension function for Kotlin developers. It's basically built on top of this androidx.activity:activity:$activity_version library.

Comment: @VaibhavGoyal I didn't even declare `androidx.activity:activity:$activity_version` in build script.

Comment: "How is this possible?" -- you have some other dependency that is pulling in `androidx.activity:activity` via a transitive dependency.

Comment: @CommonsWare edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1` [depends on `androidx.activity:activity:1.2.4`](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/appcompat/appcompat/1.3.1).

So your `implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1")` line pulls in `androidx.activity:activity:1.2.4` via the transitive dependency.

Comment: Is it possible to view all transitive dependencies in my project? Like as diagram or something? In the gradle tab I just saw my project had pulled in almost all androidx.* dependencies!!!

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB: The `dependencies` Gradle task will build you an ASCII sort of graph showing what dependencies get pulled in via transitive dependencies, for each build scenario (e.g., build variants, `test` and `androidTest`).

Answer (score 1):

I also found `com.google.android.material` imports `androidx.activity`

This became very apparent when updating dependencies for a project that compiles with api 33

```
Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0-alpha06' requires libraries
and applications that depend on it to compile against version 34 or later
of the Android APIs.

:app is currently compiled against android-33.
```